# Передать массив объектов из JS в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, массивы

Здравствуйте! У меня есть, к примеру,  массив с объектами

```js
var arr =[];
arr[i] ={ sv1: "Значение 1",
                sv2: "Значение 2 ",
                sv3: "Значение 3 "  }
//Объектов в массиве может быть сколько угодно , поэтому я обозначил как arr[i]
```

Надо передать этот массив в php, для последующего сохранения его в файл (если это возможно конечно...) Пробовал вот так  передать через AJAX, подскажите пожалуйста как принять этот массив на стороне PHP?

```js
$('#Send').click(function(){
   $.post('333.php',{
  send1:arr
  },
  function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
  });
          });
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Получилось, только беда  с кодировкой. Текст отображается крокозябликами

Comment: Кодировку исправил вот так: 
 print_r(iconv('utf-8','cp1251',$_POST['send1'])) ;

Comment: отдайте кодировку utf-8 для браузера.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно передать в виде json. Для этого переведите массив в json-строку и подставьте в Ваш код для отправки на сервер.

```
$('#Send').click(function(){
   $.post('333.php',{
     send1:JSON.stringify(arr)
     },
     function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
  });
});
```